# Loop a java application in ticks

Tags: java, ticker

I'm making a Java server application. The application would comsume alot of resources if it just ran when possible.

As far as I know if I added a sleep method, it would run like this:

```
Do task (Might take 10ms to do. Can also take longer or less)
Sleep 50ms
Do task (Might take 10ms to do. Can also take longer or less)
Sleep 50ms
```

So how can I make it run every 50ms (20 tick)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want and how it differs from your `sleep` method solution?

Comment: Are you saying you want the next iteration to run every 50ms regardless of how long the previous task took?

Comment: If you are writing a **server** that requires sleep statements to be more performant, you are doing it wrong. You should setup your main loop to wait until there's a task to be done before polling the task queue. If you aren't familiar with the primitives to accomplish this, just ask and provide more details of how your server works.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. So if the last task took 10ms it would then sleep 40ms or if the last task took 30ms it would then sleep 20ms.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your application does (you could've included it in your question), you could use a scheduler (`Quartz`, `java.util.Timer`). Which task are you trying to perform every 50ms?

Edit:

While the "game loop" is all well and good in games, servers rarely have them. Receiving data is a continuous action, and the state should change accordingly. This is a larger design issue in the server. With proper design you don't need to create artificial pauses.

For example a simple design would be having threads waiting to receive input from the clients, and when a message is received, it's processed, and a message is sent to all clients to inform of the changes. No busy waiting, nothing will happen unless a message arrives from a client.

Comment: Its a game server platform. So basicly alot every tick. Receive data, send data, calculate locations and so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    System.out.println("whatever");
}, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   // ^ rate
```

The [`scheduledAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method will schedule the given task for execution at a fixed rate, regardless of the time the task took. You could possibly have one execution take longer than 50ms, and the next one would still run (assuming you have enough threads).

Comment: I want it to run 20 times a second. If the server is overloaded it will then try to run 20 times a second.

Comment: @user3854743 It will, yes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Are you sure about this? The documentation of `scheduleAtFixedRate()` explicitly states the following: "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.". Sounds like only different tasks are executed concurrently, not the same task.

Comment: @elsamuray7 I guess _try_ is the key word in their comment. I honestly don't remember. You're absolutely right about javadoc though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I actually read some other threads and also from my own experience, it seems like the same registered task will never be executed concurrently.